# Replacing characters in filename of all files in a directory to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, ksh

I am using below script to replace characters in filename of all files to another

```
#!/bin/ksh
for e in /mapr/datalake/rawfiles/P20170626005/* ;
do mv "$e" "echo $e | sed -e 's/\P20170626*/P20170626005/g'";done
```

For example, trying to rename `P201706260001.txt => P201706260050001.txt`

But getting an error:

> cannot mv P201706260001.txt to P201706260050001.txt: no such file or
>   directory.

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: the substitution `s/\P20170626*/P20170626005/` is very doubtful

Comment: Regexes for `sed` and globbing for shell both use `*` but it means different (though related) things.  `*` in shell is approximately equivalent to `.*` in `sed`.  The backslash in `\P…` is weird.

Comment: since you've tagged `bash`, consider using http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion instead of sed...

Comment: You need to run this script from the same folder or use the full path in the first `"$e"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your mv command. Echo should be back-ticked.

Use grouping and back-reference for efficient conversions.
You can modify your script to something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for e in /mapr/datalake/rawfiles/P20170626005/*
do
    mv "$e" `echo $e | sed -e 's/\(.*\)P20170626\(.*\)/\1P20170626005\2/g'`
done
```

(.*) - Group trailing / leading filename.

\1 & \2 - Back-reference trailing / leading file name

Comment: Thanks a lot nit. This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use a similar loop to show your inputs and outputs to see what you're dealing with, eg:

```
for e in /mapr/datalake/rawfiles/P20170626005/*
do
    echo "$e"
    echo "$e" | sed -e 's/\P20170626*/P20170626005/g'
done
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time towards this issue markp. There was some problem with my command I believe, nit's answer worked out. :)